# React Native 0.64 won't build iOS app after updating Xcode to 12.5 and iOS to 14.5

Tags: ios, reactjs, xcode, react-native

After upgrading Xcode to 12.5 and iOS to 14.5, I can't run the iOS app on a real device nor in the simulator.

After running `npm run ios`, I get this message:

```
The following build commands failed:
        CompileC .../Build/Intermediates.noindex/Pods.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Flipper-Folly.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/DistributedMutex.o /Users/guilherme/Documents/Dood/ios/Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex.cpp normal x86_64 c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
```

If I try to run the app on a real device using Xcode, this is the error I get (related to Flipper-Folly):

```
.../ios/Pods/Headers/Private/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h:1051:5: 'atomic_notify_one<unsigned long>' is unavailable
```

Ideas? Thanks!

**UPDATE:**

React native has been updated to 0.64.1. You can now just change your react-native dependency to this version within your package.json file, then run `npm install`

Comment: I'm experiencing the same issue, across different react native apps as well.

Comment: There are few temporary workarounds regarding the macOs 11.3 update in React native's github https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179

Comment: Question for anyone, how is it possible that this failure started happening all of a sudden without any change on my workstation? On Monday `yarn run ios` was building fine. On Tuesday I ran the same command and got this error.

Comment: Remove "use_flipper!()" in Podfile or make comment. > pod install > run.

Comment: **Update: Official troubleshooting guide is here:** https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31480

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a solution I found [here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179#issuecomment-828361451).

Add this to your `post_install` in your Podfile:

```
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)

  ## Fix for Flipper-Folly on iOS 14.5
  find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    "atomic_notify_one(state)", "folly::atomic_notify_one(state)")

  find_and_replace("Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h",
    "atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)", "folly::atomic_wait_until(&state, previous | data, deadline)")
end
```

You'll also need to add the function def for this `find_and_replace` function (you can put this function anywhere in the podfile):

```
def find_and_replace(dir, findstr, replacestr)
  Dir[dir].each do |name|
      text = File.read(name)
      replace = text.gsub(findstr,replacestr)
      if text != replace
          puts "Fix: " + name
          File.open(name, "w") { |file| file.puts replace }
          STDOUT.flush
      end
  end
  Dir[dir + '*/'].each(&method(:find_and_replace))
end
```

Run `pod install` again and it should work. If you get an error relating to permissions while accessing the DistributedMutex-inl.h file, delete your /pods folder and run `pod install` again

You should see text print out that says Fix: Pods/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h, etc. If you don't, double check the path in the find_and_replace call.

Comment: Can you please point where we should add this function inside the podfile ?

Comment: You can drop that find_and_replace code anywhere in the Podfile.

Comment: Really just need to delete Pods/Flipper-Folly folder and the run pod install to fix the permissions issue. No need to delete the whole Pods folder.

Comment: When I try this I get an error that says "Pods/Headers/Private/Flipper-Folly/folly/synchronization/DistributedMutex-inl.h:1043:5: No member named 'folly' in namespace 'folly'; did you mean simply 'folly'?

"

Comment: if you have previously done npx pod-install, remember to delete Pods and Podfile.lock

Answer (score 9):

Solution ***without*** losing Flipper functionality:

Define the upgraded dependencies for Flipper in the **Podfile**

### React Native 62

```
def add_flipper_pods!(versions = {})
  versions['Flipper'] ||= '~> 0.87.0' 
  versions['DoubleConversion'] ||= '1.1.7'
  versions['Flipper-Folly'] ||= '~> 2.5.3' 
  versions['Flipper-Glog'] ||= '0.3.6'
  versions['Flipper-PeerTalk'] ||= '~> 0.0.4'
  versions['Flipper-RSocket'] ||= '~> 1.3.1'
```

### React Native 63

```
# Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.87.0' , 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3' , 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end
```

`cd ios && pod install` and you should be good to go

### React Native 64

Bump the version to 0.64.1 in the `package.json`

`yarn install && pod install --repo-update && react-native run-ios`

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.64.1

Comment: For React Native 63
Sadly not works and still got the bunch of errors :(

Comment: this works for me (0.63.4) `use_flipper!({'Flipper' => '0.54.0', 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.3.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.1.0'})` :)

Answer (score 8):

There is an open RN issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31179

For me commenting out `Flipper` in the `Podfile`, `pod install`, and rebuild worked as a temp solution.

```rb
  # Enables Flipper.
  #
  # Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
  # you should disable these next few lines.
  # use_flipper!
  # post_install do |installer|
  #   flipper_post_install(installer)
  # end
```

Comment: The only issue with this is that I use Firebase and Firebase can't be found without Flipper.

Comment: this solution works, just disable the flipper pod by removing that line

Answer (score 5):

React native 0.64.1 has been released and will solve this. Just update the version number in package.json.

`"react-native": "0.64.1",`

No need to modify the Podfile if you do this

Answer (score 3):

Upgrade to react native 0.64.1 (or higher)

if you moved from 0.63.x to 0.64.x make sure that in your Podfile you've updated the use_flipper! section post install:

**Before:**

```
post_install do |installer|
  flipper_post_install(installer)
end
```

**After:**

```
post_install do |installer|
  react_native_post_install(installer)
end
```

run '*npx react-native-clean-project*' from project root
then from inside '*./ios*' folder run '*pod install --repo-update*' then maybe run 'pod update'

Answer (score 2):

```
use_flipper!({ 'Flipper-Folly' => '2.5.3', 'Flipper' => '0.87.0', 'Flipper-RSocket' => '1.3.1' })
```

that works, ;)

Comment: Because React Native was updated to 0.64.1, this bug has been fixed already. No need to remove nor downgrade Flipper-Folly.

Comment: Thanks [Yesuu Bonpari](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11073948/yesuu-bonpari) yes, it worked on RN: 0.63.4 & xcode 13.0

Answer (score 0):

I know this is already answered, but for those who find this thread in the future there is an official link addressing this issue:

[Xcode 12.5 troubleshooting guide (RN 0.61/0.62/0.63/0.64)](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/31480)

Answer (score -1):

just comment out the flipper line in a pod and in Xcode also if you are not using it, hope this will fix in future updates.

```
# Note that if you have use_frameworks! enabled, Flipper will not work and
# you should disable the next line.
# use_flipper!({ 'Flipper' => '0.79.1'})
#   post_install do |installer|
#     react_native_post_install(installer)
#   end
```

IN Xcode comment all import and flipper variable